# BASH/egrep redirect to file

Tags: grep, pipe, io-redirection

I've looked, and while this is going to simple I'm guessing, its eluding me.

Simple script:

```
RDATE=`date +"%m-%d-%y %T"`
echo $RDATE >> Repo_ChangeLog
repo sync | egrep '(From)|(->)' >> Repo_ChangeLog
```

If I run the egrep by itself on a test file, its fine.  I'm missing something before the redirect >> but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Does `repo sync` output on STDOUT or STDERR?  If it outputs on STDERR, you'll need to do `repo sync 2>&1 | egrep ...` so that STDERR is included in STDOUT.

Comment: I did find that its using STDOUT and STDERR both.
Using 2>&1 will work, just doesn't show to the screen.
Trying to see if I can use something like `tee tmp -` and just make it a two step rather than an all-in-one.  Suggestions if I go that route?